# Python Nuitka library not properly functioning

Tags: python, macos, nuitka

I created the intro program on the website as follows:
https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka

I created a file called `test.py` with the following script:

```
def talk(message):
    return "Talk " + message


def main():
    print(talk("Hello World"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and I ran the code in VS code to made sure it worked properly and it seemed to work fine.

So I type the following into the terminal to get the program created:

```
python -m nuitka --show-progress test.py
```

and the following progress shows up in the terminal:

```
Nuitka-Options:INFO: Used command line options: --show-progress test.py
Nuitka:WARNING: The Python version '3.11' is only experimentally supported by Nuitka '1.5.7', but an upcoming
Nuitka:WARNING: release will change that. In the mean time use Python version '3.10' instead or newer Nuitka.
Nuitka-Options:WARNING: You did not specify to follow or include anything but main program. Check options and
Nuitka-Options:WARNING: make sure that is intended.
Nuitka:INFO: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '1.5.7' on Python '3.11' commercial grade 'not installed'.
Nuitka-Memory:INFO: Total memory usage before processing:: 47.05 MB (49332224 bytes)
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: PASS 1:
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Optimizing module '__main__', 0 more modules to go after that.
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Doing module local optimizations for '__main__'.
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Not finished with the module due to following change kinds: new_expression,new_statements
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Not finished with the module due to following change kinds: new_builtin_ref,new_expression,var_usage
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Not finished with the module due to following change kinds: new_constant,new_expression,new_statements
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Not changed, but retrying one more time.
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Finished with the module.      
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: PASS 2:                        
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Optimizing module '__main__', 0 more modules to go after that.
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Doing module local optimizations for '__main__'.
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Finished with the module.      
Nuitka:INFO: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.
Nuitka:INFO: Generating source code for C backend compiler.
Nuitka-Memory:INFO: Total memory usage before generating C code:: 47.44 MB (49741824 bytes)
Nuitka-Memory:INFO: Total memory usage before running scons: 49.91 MB (52330496 bytes)
Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
Nuitka:INFO: Running C compilation via Scons.
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: clang (clang).
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend linking program with 6 files (no progress information available).
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Compiled 6 C files using ccache.
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Cached C files (using ccache) with result 'cache hit': 6
Nuitka:INFO: Keeping build directory 'test.build'.
Nuitka:INFO: Successfully created 'test.bin'.
```

and then I am left with two files.The `test.bin` MacBinary archive and the `test.build` folder. When I go to try and open or even extract the `test.bin` file I get the following error:

`Unable to expand "test.bin". It is in an unsupported format.`

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I have been using pyinstaller for a long time but I've heard that nuitka makes the program quicker so I thought I'd give it a try instead. Keep in mind that I am very new to macOS so it could very well be something obvious that I just can't think of.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to extract the .bin file? On linux (which often behaves the same as Mac), you can run the code by typing

./test.bin

No need to extract/expand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).